# Should we blacklist the medical-advice tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

This particular tag was originally discussed here: [*Should we create a medical advice tag?*](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/283/70)

Questions asking for medical advice are [specifically mentioned](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as off topic, so to me it makes no sense to have the tag [medical-advice](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical-advice). The [tag info](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tags/medical-advice/info) even advises not to use it.

If we blacklist it it means that it is eliminated and it cannot be recreated.

So... blacklist it? Or keep it?

Answer (score 4):

In the Biology and Cognitive Sciences Stack, where I am most active, self-help questions with a medical background are explicitly considered off-topic. In other words, those questions where a professional care giver should do a proper medical (physical or psychological) exam, are closed.

At Bio we can close vote as off-topic for the reason of:

> Personal medical questions and health advice are off-topic on Biology. We cannot safely answer questions for your specific situation and you should always consult a doctor for medical advice.

Something similar may be appropriate here too I guess - in other words, not only the tag can go, all questions based on medical self-help should be put on hold imo.

Answer (score 3):

I think blacklisting might be a bit extreme considering that there aren't that many questions tagged with it currently. I'm in favor of removing the tag from the questions and even re-tag the questions more appropriately if necessary.